# Change to PHP Array from String

Tags: php, arrays, explode

I Have an string from my database, like :

```
$arr = [{"detail":"33,putih","sku":"123","price":"21","stok":"5"},{"detail":"33,hitam","sku":"528","price":"75","stok":"5"},{"detail":"34,hitam","sku":"775","price":"49","stok":"5"}]
```

But i want to convert this string to array, i was try use explode like :

```
$array = explode('{"', $arr);
```

i was confused of the result and how to get it,
But the result not like i want. I want i can get only sku[0] or detail[0] and else.

Comment: How did that string get built? Looks like it is JSON or a serialized string. You should use the decode function of what ever built it.

Comment: Use `json_decode($arr, true)`: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php

Comment: OMG thx a lot @Nikita Leshchev. :D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I extract data from JSON with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-do-i-extract-data-from-json-with-php)

Comment: @AndyAjhisRamadhan you're welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `json_decode()` method in PHP to convert your JSON string to `array`:

```
$str_json = '[{"detail":"33,putih","sku":"123","price":"21","stok":"5"},{"detail":"33,hitam","sku":"528","price":"75","stok":"5"},{"detail":"34,hitam","sku":"775","price":"49","stok":"5"}]';

$arr = json_decode($str_json,true);
```

The second parameter of `json_decode()` function is set to `true` which will result in an associative array.

Comment: Thank you Mister :)